# How to compare strings in an "if" statement?

Tags: c, string

I want to test and see if a variable of type "char" can compare with a regular string like "cheese" for a comparison like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char favoriteDairyProduct[30];

    scanf("%s",favoriteDairyProduct);

    if(favoriteDairyProduct == "cheese")
    {
        printf("You like cheese too!");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("I like cheese more.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(What I actually want to do is much longer than this but this is the main part I'm stuck on.)
So how would one compare two strings in C?

Comment: By the way, using scanf() like that is a very serious bug. If you enter a word longer than 30 characters, your program will probably crash. fgets() is safer.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You're looking for the function `strcmp`, or `strncmp` from `string.h`.

Since strings are just arrays, you need to compare each character, so this function will do that for you:

```
if (strcmp(favoriteDairyProduct, "cheese") == 0)
{
    printf("You like cheese too!");
}
else
{
    printf("I like cheese more.");
}
```

Further reading: [strcmp at cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/)

Answer (score 5):

```
if(strcmp(aString, bString) == 0){
    //strings are the same
}
```

godspeed

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the functions [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) and [strncmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/).

Answer (score 4):

```
if(!strcmp(favoriteDairyProduct, "cheese"))
{
    printf("You like cheese too!");
}
else
{
    printf("I like cheese more.");
}
```

Comment: What is different here than the accepted answer?

Comment: @zar Simple difference, but difference the negation instead of ==0.

Answer (score 3):

You can't compare array of characters using `==` operator. You have to use string compare functions. Take a look at [Strings (c-faq)](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx8.html).

> The standard library's `strcmp` function compares two strings, and returns 0 if they are identical, or a negative number if the first string is alphabetically "less than" the second string, or a positive number if the first string is "greater."