# How to fix if-statement error and "Result of comparison against a string literal is unspecified"?

Tags: c, xcode, macos, if-statement

So, I'm just starting out (excuse my noob-ness), and I'm working on a C program on a Mac with Xcode. It's basically just a scanf() and then a ton of if statements that produce a pre-determined output. I've wrote it so that Xcode compiles it without bitching, but I'm getting a strange "Fix-it" error and no output when I try to run it.

```
char planet[9];

printf("Input the name of a planet\n");

 scanf("%c", &planet);

if (planet == "Earth")
    {printf("Earth is 150 million kilometers away from the sun");}

if (planet == "Mars") 
    {printf("Mars is 220 million kilometers away from the sun");} 

if (planet == ("Mercury"))
{printf("Mercury is 57 million kilometers from the sun");}

if (planet == ("Venus"))
    {printf("Venus is 108 million kilometers from the sun");}

if (planet == ("Jupiter"))
    {printf("Jupiter is 779 million kilometers from the sun");}

if (planet == ("Saturn"))
    {printf("Saturn is 1.73 billion kilometers from the sun");}

if (planet == ("Uranus"))
    {printf ("Uranus (haha) is 2.88 billion kilometers from the sun");} 

if (planet == ("Neptune"))
    {printf("Neptune is 4.5 billion kilometers from the sun");}

    return 0;
```

is the code itself but I can't get it to work.

Here's a link to the Xcode project as well.

https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=252616984794310&set=a.106237419432268.11635.100001380326478&type=1&theater

Comment: What happens when you use `scanf("%s", &planet);`? Oh, you could have mentioned the planet `Klingon` in there too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare strings in an "if" statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222495/how-to-compare-strings-in-an-if-statement) This one comes out first if I search on SO for "[C] compare string". Please use the search capabilities of SO before asking.

Answer (score 4):

The address of `planet` will never be equal to the address of any of those string literals. You need to use `strcmp` to compare the *contents* of strings rather than comparing their addresses.

Comment: I love how all the answers are all pretty much the same.  Also, case insensitive strcmp is `strcasecmp`.  Just saying!  :-)

Answer (score 4):

You'd be much happier using `strcmp`:

```
if (strcmp(planet, "Earth") == 0) {
    ...
}
```

Also, `%c` scans one character, not a string.  You need to use `%s` to scan a string.  And you need to specify a maximum length to avoid overflowing your buffer:

```
scanf("%8s", planet);
```

The maximum length is one less than the buffer size because you have to leave room for the NUL terminator.

Answer (score 0):

Your are **comparing addresses** of planet to the address of those string literals..so the addresses will not be same. You should instead compare content of both strings so do as follows:

First include `<string.h>` and in each if statement write like this

```
if(!strcmp ( planet,"Earth" ))
```

As c strings can not be compared directly you need to use strcmp function for that.

**strcmp function**

```
int strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
```

this function compare two strings and return value will be :

a) A zero value indicates that both strings are equal.

b) A value greater than zero indicates that the first character that does not match has a greater value in str1 than in str2; And

c) a value less than zero indicates the opposite.