# While loop not stopping when arguments are equal

Tags: c

I am running this program with with *./crack 50yoN9fp966dU

50yoN9fp966dU* is crimson encrypted. which is on the word list. My program is as follow:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc > 2)  
    {
        printf("Invalid Argument \n");
        return 1;
    } 
    else 
    {
        FILE *fp1;
        fp1 = fopen("/usr/share/dict/words", "r");
        char line[9];
        while (fgets(line, 9, fp1) != NULL)
        {
            char *EncryptLine1;
            char *EncryptLine2;
            printf("%s", line);
            EncryptLine1 = crypt(line, "50"); 
            if(argv[1] == EncryptLine1)
            {
                printf("%s \n", line);
            }
            EncryptLine2 = crypt(line, "HA");
            if(argv[1] == EncryptLine2)
            {
                printf("%s \n", EncryptLine2);
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

If I add a `printf("%s", EncryptLine1)`, I see the `argv[1]`, i.e *50yoN9fp966dU*, but the loop continue and does not print the answer.

Comment: Try using strcmp to compare strings. I belive using double equation signs doesn't work in c with strings.

Comment: You are comparing memory location (addresses). To compare strings use `strcmp()` and family.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some problems in your code:

1. You blithely assume `argc` will never be smaller than 2. Check for unequal 2 instead of bigger two in your first condition.
   Anyway, if you return out of an if-block, using else and doing deeper nesting is really superfluous.
2. [Strings cannot be compared with `==`, use `strcmp`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8222495):

   ```
   if( ! strcmp(argv[1], EncryptLine1))
   ```
3. You need to add a `break` to break out of the loop or a `return` to leave the function in your conditional block after printing success, if you want to end the loop there.

   ```
   if( ! strcmp(argv[1], EncryptLine1)) {
       printf("%s \n", line);
       break;
   }
   ```

BTW: Why don't you reuse `EncryptLine1` (not that you need any temporary at all there)?

Answer (score 2):

**You are doing pointer comparison instead of contents (pointed data) comparison.**

Change this:

```
if (argv[1] == EncryptLine1)
```

To this:

```
if (strcmp(argv[1],EncryptLine1) == 0)
```

And this:

```
if (argv[1] == EncryptLine2)
```

To this:

```
if (strcmp(argv[1],EncryptLine2) == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

`argv[1]`, `EncryptLine1` and `EncryptLine2` are all `char*`s. `operator==` on two `char*`s simply checks to see if they are pointing to the same memory location. What you want is to compare the contents of the strings they represent. So, the `if`s should look like this:

```
if(!strcmp(argv[1], EncryptLine1))
```