# How to compare two char arrays in C?

Tags: c, newline, c-strings, fgets, strcmp

I'm coming from Python and there you can easily compare two strings (char arrays) like that:

```
if "foo" == "bar":
    # ...
```

How would I do this in C? I already saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222495/how-to-compare-strings-in-an-if-statement) but it didn't work.

Code:

```
int main(void) {

    char string[100];
    
    printf("Please enter something: ");
    fgets(string, 100, stdin);

    if (strcmp(string, "a") == 0)
        printf("a");

    else if (strcmp(string, "b") == 0)
        printf("b");

    else if (strcmp(string, "c") == 0)
        printf("c");

    else
        printf("something else");


    return (0);
}
```

It prints "something else" though I entered `a`.

Comment: The problem is most likely the newline that `fgets` includes in the buffer.

Comment: In this case with string literals, you can simply use `memcmp(string, "a", sizeof("a")-1);` or similar.

Comment: "but it doesn't work at me" --> is is working and you are comparing strings correctly and they are not equal.  It is just that the input string is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `fgets` can append to the entered string the new line character `'\n'` that you should remove. For example

```
fgets(string, 100, stdin);
string[ strcspn( string, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

or

```
fgets(string, 100, stdin);
char *p = strchr( string, '\n' );
if ( p != NULL ) *p = '\0';
```

From the C Standard (7.21.7.2 The fgets function)

> 2 The fgets function reads at most one less than the number of
> characters specified by n from the stream pointed to by stream into
> the array pointed to by s. **No additional characters are read after a
> new-line character (which is retained)** or after end-of-file. A null
> character is written immediately after the last character read into
> the array.

Comment: Thank you! What does the if statement part?

Comment: @puncher If the new line character '\n' is not found in the string then the function strchr returns a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The `fgets()` also takes in the newline character when the user presses the **Enter key**. So in order to remove that from what is stored in `string[100], just change :

```
fgets(string, 100, stdin);
```

to

```
strtok(fgets(string, 100, stdin), "\n");
```

to remove the newline character. Just make sure to include the `#include <string.h>` header

### **Further Reading**

If you are wondering what `strtok` does, have a look at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm

> The C library function char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim)
> breaks string str into a series of tokens using the delimiter delim.
>
> `char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim)`

Comment: `strtok(string, "\n");` fails to remove the `'\n'` when buffer is `"\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

You could answer this question yourself if you did put some research effort.

```
int main(void) {

    char string[100];
    
    printf("Please enter something: ");
    fgets(string, 100, stdin);

    if (strcmp(string, "a") == 0)
        printf("a");

    else if (strcmp(string, "b") == 0)
        printf("b");

    else if (strcmp(string, "c") == 0)
        printf("c");

    else
    {
        printf("something else - lets check why:\n Entered string:\n");
        for(size_t n = 0; n <= strlen(string); n++)
        {
            printf("string[%2zu] = ", n);
            switch(string[n])
            {
                case '\n':
                    printf("\\n");
                    break;
                case '\r':
                    printf("\\r");
                    break;
                case 0:
                    printf("null char");
                    break;
                default:
                    if(string[n] < ' ' || string[n] > 127)
                    {
                        printf("\\x%x", (unsigned)string[n]);
                    }
                    else
                    printf("'%c'", string[n]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }


    return (0);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/afb3Ej7E9